# Dependency Injection, inheritance and generics

Tags: generics, inheritance, dependency-injection

I am using dependency injection and have come up against something I can't figure out.  I have a base class that needs a generic logger:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass(ILogger<BaseClass> logger)
    {
        // code here
    }
}
```

Then I have a class inheriting that also needs the generic logger:

```
public class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    public SubClass(ILogger<SubClass> logger)
    {
        // code here
    }
}
```

The problem is that this does not compile with the message; *BaseClass does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments*.

This would be easy to solve if I could do this:

```
public SubClass(ILogger<SubClass> logger) : base(logger)
```

The problem is that this is not legal either since `ILogger<SubClass>` is not an instance of `ILogger<BaseClass>` (it does not compile with *The best overloaded match for ... has some invalid arguments*).

**One possible solution:**
I guess I do not have to use constructor injection and instead use the `DependencyResolver`.

**The question:** Surely someone else have come up against this issue before?  Is it possible to do with constructor injection?  If so, what should I do?

**Note:** In the current project I am using `StructureMap` ([for MVC4](http://www.nuget.org/packages/StructureMap.MVC4/)), but I think that the tool here is slightly irrelevant.

Comment: If you find yourself injecting the same dependencies into different classes to do the same thing, you might want to look into Interception.

Comment: @FacioRatio Thanks for your insight.  Afterwards I read http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/139111/interception-vs-injection-a-framework-architecture-decision which was very interesting.  As I noted elsewhere, the `ILogger<T>` is in use in many different solutions and projects already through DI, but for future solutions this is certainly worth considering.

Comment: Decoration is nice, but when you end up with many decorators that do the same thing, it's time for Interception. See: http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Advanced-scenarios#Interception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you change the logger interface to be :

```
interface ILogger<out T> where T : BaseClass
```

Comment: +1  I have to admit that when I googled `out` used in this way I had to really think over what is happening.  It did solve the compilation problem and I do think the way this class is used that this is a valid way of solving the problem.  I'm marking it as the correct answer even though my mind is not really wrapping itself around the consequences of using this.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `ILogger<SubClass>` is not a subclass of `ILogger<BaseClass>` so compiler think that you wrote a new constructor. This is implicitly equivalent if you wrote

```
public class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    public SubClass(ILogger<SubClass> logger)
        : base() // since base class does not have a constructor 
                 // with no arguments, you will get the error
    {
        // code here
    }
}
```

So your question is not about dependency injection exactly. It is more about your architecture.

Comment: I accept that this could be an architecture issue (and I do understand the error messages), but are you saying that I can't use DI through the constructor with this generic class (the `Ilogger<T>`)?

Comment: DI is just a tool to automate things that you can do manually. If you can compile your code then you can use DI :) I would like to think are you really need to `ILogger` have a generic parameter?

Comment: The `ILogger` is in use in too many projects to change it to not be generic.  It is old legacy code that is well used (and useful).  Thanks for your input anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You could add a parameterless constructor in your `BaseClass` which would call the parameterized constructor and pass it a manually resolved `ILogger` instance. Something like this:

```
public BaseClass()
    : this(ResolveLogger())
{
}

private static ILogger<BaseClass> ResolveLogger()
{
    // resolve the instance manually and return it
}
```

This way, if an instance of type `BaseClass` is resolved, it would use the parameterized constructor and inject a resolved `ILogger<BaseClass>` instance. But if a derived class is resolved, this derived class would call the parameterless `BaseClass()` constructor and the `ILogger<BaseClass>` would be resolved manually.

Comment: +1 This would be a valid way of solving the issue.  I wanted to try to solve it without having to manually resolve the logger, so I am giving another answer the correct answer check mark.  Thnaks for your help!